# What is wrong in my go's code(IO wait)?

Tags: go

What is wrong in my go's code(IO wait)?

I design my middlewares but reached errors(IO wait) when i run the command:

```
ab -c 100 -n 100000 -k  http://127.0.0.1:10000/
```

The complete code is as follows:
https://github.com/HeadwindFly/examples/blob/master/middleware.go

Comment: Consider posting the relevant code here. We do need [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in here.

Comment: @J.Chomel sorry for that, but the code is too long, stackoverflow does not allow to post if the question contains most of code.

Comment: Code too long: That is why I advise you should create an MVCE. But if you don't have it, someone might take the required time to help you, who knows.

Comment: What are `errors(IO wait)`? (and there are much better tools than `ab`, which might be part of your problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: no reason to use reflect here.  Has nothing to do with your problem, but it isn't needed.

In your setup of Context, you are using a global var for ctx.

go's http server is concurrent, so what you are doing is having multiple goroutines update the same global var and then pass that to the handler.

This causes your handlers to sometimes get the same ResponseWriter instance and attempt to write to it.  This can cause `ab` to fail since you are writing invalid http responses by mixing what gets sent on the wire.

Get rid of global ctx variable and use a local one, like below:

```
func handler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := &Context{ // notice that this is a local var now
        names:make([]string, 0),
        rw:rw,
        r:r,
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(middlewareInfos); i++ {
        middleware := reflect.New(middlewareInfos[i].t)

        setContextMethod := middleware.MethodByName("SetContext")
        setContextMethod.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(ctx)})

        handleMethod := middleware.MethodByName("Handle")
        values := handleMethod.Call([]reflect.Value{})

        if value, ok := values[0].Interface().(bool); !ok || !value {
            return
        }
    }

    // fmt.Printf("%v\n", ctx)

    fmt.Fprint(rw, "Hello World.")
}
```